# Assembly language with C++

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, floating-point

I should write the program using C++ and Assembly. Program must count the average of the array.

The CPP file must take the data from the user and display the result.In the array must be the real numbers (with floating-point).

The ASM file must count the average of this array.

That is the .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#define L 4

extern "C" float average(float* tab, int G);

int main()
{
    float tab[L]={0};
    cout<<"Enter array: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<L; i++)
        cin >> tab[i];
    cout << "Average value of entered array = " << average(tab, L);
    cout << "\nThe end of the programm\n";
    return 0;
 }
```

And here is my assembly code:

```
.386
.model SMALL,c
PUBLIC average
.stack 100h
.data

.code
average PROC

push ebp                       
mov ebp, esp               
push esi                    

mov ecx, [ebp+12]           
mov esi, [ebp+8]           

finit                           ;coprocessor
fldz                        

sum:                           
    fadd dword ptr [esi+ecx-4]  ;ST(0)=ST(0)+ST(i)

 loop sum                       ;retry sum while cx!=0

 fidiv dword ptr [ebp+12]       ;Division

 pop esi                        ;End of the programm
 pop ebp 

 mov eax, esi                    
 ret    8  

 average ENDP
 END
```

The result always is 2.422547e+198

Where I have the mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try writing the function `average` in C++, compiling it, and comparing with the asm you wrote? By the way you need to specify the system you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an array of floats each taking 4 bytes you should multiply the index by 4. Also note that C calling convention mandates that the caller will free the arguments, as such your "`ret 8`" is wrong.

The `mov eax, esi` at the end is irrelevant.